# How to fix automatic disable of touchpad on windows?

Tags: windows

Recently, my windows 10 machine touchpad is getting disabled once I login.

If I goto settings --> touchpad, it is disabled.

[image: touchpad settings]

If I enable, the touchpad works, but to do that I need to connect to an external mouse and do that everytime.

Even if I enable here, once I restart machine, it is getting disabled again.

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a mouse plugged in along with the touchpad?

Comment: No, I connected just to turn this on and removed.

Comment: You can try updating your touchpad or trackpad drivers. This may help you in fixing this issue.